# Recovering element of an array, given sums of items at indexes matching bitmasks

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there was an array `E` of `2^n` elements. For example:

```
E = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Unfortunately, someone has come along and scrambled the array. They took all elements whose index in binary is of the form `1XX`, and added them into the elements at index `0XX` (i.e. they did `E[0] += E[1]`, `E[2] += E[3]`, etc. Then they did the same thing for indexes like `X1X` into `X0X`, and for `XX1` into `XX0`.

More specifically, they ran this pseudo-code over the array:

```
def scramble(e):
    n = lg_2(len(e))
    for p in range(n):
        m = 1 << p
        for i in range(len(e)):
            if (i & m) != 0:
                e[i - m] += e[i]
```

In terms of our example, this causes:

```
E_1 = [2+3, 3, 5+7, 7, 11+13, 13, 17+19, 19]
E_1 = [5, 3, 12, 7, 24, 13, 36, 19]

E_2 = [5+12, 3+7, 12, 7, 24+36, 13+19, 36, 19]
E_2 = [17, 10, 12, 7, 60, 32, 36, 19]

E_3 = [17+60, 10+32, 12+36, 7+19, 60, 32, 36, 19]
E_3 = [77, 42, 48, 26, 60, 32, 36, 19]
```

You're given the array after it's been scrambled (i.e. your input is `E_3`). Your goal is to recover the original first element of `E`, (i.e. the number 2).

One way to get the 2 back is undo all the scrambling. Run the scrambling code, but with the `+=` replaced by a `-=`. However, doing that is very expensive. It takes `n 2^n` time. Is there a faster way?

**Alternate Form**

Stated another way, I give you an array `S` where the element at index `i` is the sum of all elements with an index `j` satisfying `(j & i) == i`from a list `E`. For example, `S[101110]` is `E[101110] + E[111110] + E[101111] + E[111111]`). How expensive is it to recover an element of `E`, given `S`?

The item at `111111...` is easy, because `S[111111...] = E[111111...]`, but `S[000000...]` depends on a *all* the elements from `E` in a non-uniform way so it seems to be harder to get back.

**Extended**

What if we don't just want to recover the original items, but want to recover sums of the original items that have match a mask that can specify must-be-1, no-constraint, **and** must-be-0? Is this harder?

Comment: I'm having trouble following what you're talking about.  To begin with, do you mean `n=3`, so that `E` has `2^3=8` elements?  "They took all elements whose binary index ..." confuses me.  Could you present the (pseudo-)code for this scrambling procedure?  Could you present your `n 2^n` process for unscrambling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the number of items in the array `N`, and the size of the bitmasks being used `B` so `N = 2^B`.

You can't do better than `O(N)`.

The example solution in the question, which just runs the scrambling in reverse, takes `O(N B)` time. We can reduce that to `O(N)` by discarding items that won't contribute to the actual value we read at the end. This makes the unscrambling much simpler, actually: just iteratively subtract the last half of the array from the first half, then discard the last half, until you have one item left.

```
def unscrambleFirst(S):
    while len(S) > 1:
        h = len(S)/2
        for i in range(h):
            S = S[:h] - S[h:] #item-by-item subtraction
    return S[0]
```

It's not possible to go faster than `O(N)`. We can prove it with linear algebra.

- The original array has `N` independent items, i.e. it is a vector with `N` degrees of freedom.
- The scrambling operation only uses linear operations, and so is equivalent to multiplying that vector by a matrix. (The matrix is `[[1, 1], [0, 1]]` [tiled inside of itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) `B` times; it ends up looking like a [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle)).
- The scrambling operation matrix is invertible (that's why we can undo the scrambling).
- Therefore the scrambled vector must still have `N` degrees of freedom.
- But our `O(N)` solution is a linear combination of every element of the scrambled vector.
- And since the elements of the scrambled vector must all be linearly independent for there to be `N` degrees of freedom in it, we can't rewrite the usage of any one element with usage of the others.
- Therefore we can't change which items we rely on, and we know that we rely on all of them in one case so it must be all of them in all cases.

Hopefully that's clear enough. The scrambling distributes the first item in a way that requires you to look at every item to get it back.